# Reshaping Keras tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

How can I reshape Keras tensor from shape (1,1,10) to shape (10) without specifying initial input shape?
Using Flatten()(as a command) gives

```
 <tf.Tensor 'flatten_11/Reshape:0' shape=(?, ?) dtype=float32>
```

as an output
and gives a mistake while using it in model

```
model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution1D(filters=self.nb_filters,
                            kernel_size=self.n_gram,
                            padding='valid',
                            activation='relu',
                            input_shape=(None,3*self.vecsize)))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3*self.vecsize-self.n_gram+1))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(num_categories, activation='softmax'))
```

It says:
   **The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined (got (None, 10). Make sure to pass a complete "input_shape" or "batch_input_shape" argument to the first layer in your model.**

Initial input shape is 1*arbitrary dimension*vecsize, and I strongly don't want to specify the arbitrary dimension beforehand.

Using Flatten((1,1,10)) instead of just Flatten() also produces an error:

**TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**

So what should I do to make it work?

Comment: By the message given, it sounds your output `(None,10)` is already exactly the shape you need for `Dense`. It seems no reshaping is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

When giving the `input_shape` of the first layer, you must not add the `None` part. That is reserved to the batch size and will be automatically inferred when training or predicting.

So, when defining your first `Convolution1D`, your `input_shape` should be just `input_shape = (3*self.vecsize,1)`, if you're using channels last, or `(1,3*self.vecsize)` if you're using channels first.

Comment: While adding it into a model instead of Flatten, it throws
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: Ah, now I see what got wrong. The `input_shape` you pass to the first layer should not consider the `None` part.

Answer (score 1):

This is of course assumption from NumPy. We all familiar with reshaping arrays with np.reshape(-1,224,224,3). That's NumPy format. However, I'm directly posting a code to you from Keras' documentation.

```
as first layer in a Sequential model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape((3, 4), input_shape=(12,)))
now: model.output_shape == (None, 3, 4)
note: `None` is the batch dimension

intermediate layer in a Sequential model
model.add(Reshape((6, 2)))
now: model.output_shape == (None, 6, 2)

also supports shape inference using `-1` as dimension
model.add(Reshape((-1, 2, 2)))
now: model.output_shape == (None, 3, 2, 2)
```

You can see that its format is

```
model.add(Reshape((targetsize)))
```

Hope it helps.